# Image not displaying in Tkinter Label widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get an image to display in a Tkinter Label widget. This code works inside a class in PyCharm, but doesn't get past the 'tk.Label' line in the main app. I've consulted other answers here but haven't been able to figure out why the image isn't displaying in the main app.

```
logo_filepath = "/Users/xxx/MASTER/pymol/Master/cache/logos/tmpbhWv2Ts.gif"
self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file = logo_filepath)
self.logo = tk.Label(self, image=self.img)
self.logo.photo = self.img
self.logo.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=10, columnspan=4)
```

Comment: why doesn't it "get past" that line? Does your computer crash?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the issue? Something like an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

It's a very simple error. Just make sure that you aren't defining `self.[Your Variable]` outside of a class. Because `self` is only available in classes. Also, Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

logo_filepath = "Your File Path..."
img = tk.PhotoImage(file = logo_filepath)
logo = tk.Label(root, image=img)
logo.photo = img
logo.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=10, columnspan=4)

tk.mainloop()
```